# Passport JWT unauthorized after logging in

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

My app with passport-JWT don't want to work properly as after login I can see only

> Unauthorized

the login algorythm itself works good as it checks user credentials etc. but the part where passport should use `JWTStrategy` doesn't work at all. I went across multiple questions and answers here, in stackoverflow hoping to find an answer but I can't see anything helpful. The whole concept I made was built using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/learn-using-jwt-with-passport-authentication-9761539c4314) but changing small details

```
fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken => fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')
```

but still it doesn't work. after logging in I can't see any new cookies set on my browser or something. Where the problem could be? The main thing is that I can't even reach and print `console.trace(jwtPayload);` on my Passport.js:

```js
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const passportJWT = require("passport-jwt");
const ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;
const JWTStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy;

const models = require('../models/index');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'name',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, (user, password, cb) => {
    return models.User.findOne({
        attributes: ['id', 'user_password', 'user_name'],
        where: {user_name: user}
    }).then(User => {
        if (!User) return cb(null, false, {message: 'No matching results for such a user.'});
        return User.validPassword(password).then(result => {
            if (result !== true) return cb(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password for selected user'});
            return cb(null, User.get({plain: true}), {
                message: 'Logged In Successfully'
            });
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        return cb(err);
    });
}));

let options = {};
options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
options.secretOrKey = 'token';
options.expiresIn = (86400 * 30);
console.log(options);

passport.use(new JWTStrategy(options, function(jwtPayload, cb){
    console.trace(jwtPayload);
    return models.User.findOneById(jwtPayload.id).then(User => {
        console.log(User);
        if (User) {
            return cb(null, User.get({plain: true}));
        } else {
            return cb(null, false);
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return cb(err);
    });
}));
```

and also my router to handle authentication

```
router.post('/doAuth', function (req, res, next) {

passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
    if (err || !user) {
        return res.json({
            message: info ? info.message : 'Login failed',
            status: 'error'
        });
    }

    req.login(user, {session: false}, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                message: err,
                status: 'error'
            });
        }

        const token = jwt.sign(user, 'token', {expiresIn: 86400 * 30});
        return res.json({
            message: 'Logged In Successfully!',
            redirect: '/dashboard',
            token: 'jwt ' + token,
            success: true,
            user: {
                id: user.id,
                name: user.user_name
            }
        });
    });
})
(req, res);

});
```

so after logging in I'm being redirected to `/dashboard` as it should be but there I can only see Unauthorized. Also in my app.js I'm using authenticate.

```
const passport = require('passport');
require(Paths.Helpers + 'Passport');

app.use('/dashboard', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), userRouter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the fromAuthHeaderWithScheme to check for the token. According to the readme that

> creates a new extractor that looks for the JWT in the authorization header, expecting the scheme to match auth_scheme.

That means that when you get the token when logging in with `/login`, you need to supply it to the `/dashboard` in the Authorization Header of the request. Does your request include the jwt-token in the Header?